# Javascript - onmouseout doesn't fire when using z-index

Tags: javascript

I seem to be having trouble with onmouseout not firing when the object is above another element. In my example moving out to the right top or bottom triggers the mouseout event straight away, but moving to the left it doesn't fire.

http://jsfiddle.net/S44fM/

```
<html>
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript">

var viewedCont;

function view_img(){
viewedCont = document.getElementById('view-container');
viewedCont.style.display='block';
}


function view_img_stop(){
viewedCont.style.display='none';

}

</script>

<style>
$css_inPage

#roll{
z-index:100;
background-color:#0000CC;
height:400px;
width:200px;
}

#view-container{
display:none;
width:355px;
height:402px;
z-index:9999;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#CCCCCC;

margin-left:230px;
margin-bottom:90px;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="view-container" onmouseout="view_img_stop()">
</div>


<div  style="margin-left:200px">
<div  id="roll"  onmouseover="view_img();"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour happens because, when you move to the left the first event that fires is onmouseout of #view-container trying to make it go away. However before it goes away you have moved already over at the small part of #roll and the event onmouseover of #roll also fires following the previous event and the #view-container is shown again. So you basically need to handle the onmouseout event of #roll, or make the #view-container cover the whole part of #roll.

So modifying it as so i think will work as you want it,

```
<body>

<div id="view-container" onmouseout="view_img_stop()" onmouseover="view_img();">
</div>


<div  style="margin-left:200px">
<div  id="roll"  onmouseover="view_img();" onmouseout="view_img_stop()"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S44fM/2/